# scaffolding an oracle database from dotnet CLI

Tags: entity-framework-core, odp.net

I'm competent in C#, and a bit vague on oracle and dotnet cli.

what I want to do is, create a console app from the command line, and create a EF model from the command line, "database first".

I've got this working through visual studio, i.e. create a console app, add the packages
Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework
Oracle.ManagedDataAccess

create a "data connection" to my oracle database.

Add an ado.net entity data model, and use the wizard to select a single table, and apply it and it creates me a model, I can then query the database with.

so from the command line?

```
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef
dotnet tool update --global dotnet-ef
dotnet new console
dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFramework.Design
```

build it with
dotnet build

and its fine (not surprisingly)

then, I'm completely baffled by the difference between the "manageddataaccess" and things like Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore....

so take your pick either way (it will still fail).

```
dotnet add package Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore
```

now ....

```
dotnet build
```

and NU1107 version conflict detected for Microsoft.Relational ....

if you install the explicit version, then "Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore 3.19.80 requires...." an older version....so these things just don't work together.

any ideas?

if you plough on (its only a warning!) and try to scaffold then unsurprisingly it fails with some sort of method not found error (obviously because we've got the wrong package).

All the online docs seem to do something in visual studio with the package manager, which isnt really any use to me, I want to be able to generate this code from the command line for a build script.

(and actually having the documentation reference a CLI run through is much more explicit).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so the issue is versions (and can I say an almost complete lack of clear documentation/examples)

this works (at least it scaffolds the table I want, whether there are more issues downstream I dont know)

```
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef
dotnet tool update --global dotnet-ef
dotnet new web -f netcoreapp3.1 
dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore --version 3.1.8
dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools --version 3.1.8
dotnet add package Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore --version 3.19.80
dotnet ef DbContext scaffold "Data Source=myserver:1521/mydatabase; User ID=me;Password=mypassword;" Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore -t ATABLE
```

I may try paket rather than nuget and see if it works out the dependency relationships a bit more automatically, rather than me having to piece it together.